# How to solve an equation for a particular variable

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve for `Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]` from the following expression, when this expression is equal to 0.

```
expr1 = Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 14]] Sin[
    Subscript[\[Theta], 
     14]] (-Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 14]] Cos[
       Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[
       Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[
       I Subscript[ \[Delta], 14]] + 
     Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Sin[
       Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[
       Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[
       I (Subscript[\[Delta], 24] + Subscript[\[Delta], 13])] - 
     Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[
       Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[
       I Subscript[\[Delta], 13]] - 
     Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[
       Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] - 
     Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Cos[
       Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[
       I[Subscript[\[Delta], 24]]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
eq = Subscript[\[Theta],14] (-Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 14]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I Subscript[\[Delta], 14]] + Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I (Subscript[\[Delta], 24] + Subscript[\[Delta], 13])] -Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I Subscript[\[Delta], 13]] - Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] - Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I[Subscript[\[Delta], 24]]])
Solve[eq == 0, Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve for `Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]`, you'll need to substitute with a variable for that represents this quantity. The easiest way would be:

```
eq = Subscript[\[Theta],14] (-Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 14]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I Subscript[\[Delta], 14]] + Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I (Subscript[\[Delta], 24] + Subscript[\[Delta], 13])] -Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I Subscript[\[Delta], 13]] - Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] - Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 34]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 24]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Exp[I[Subscript[\[Delta], 24]]])

Solve[
  eq == 0 /. {
    Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] -> sin\[Theta]12,
    Subscript[\[Theta], 12] -> ArcSin[sin\[Theta]12]
  },
  sin\[Theta]12
]
```

The first rule is there to make all the sines disappear; the second rule takes care of all the remaining instances of `Subscript[\[Theta], 12]`.